# How to run corda nodes individually without running runnodes?

Tags: blockchain, corda

I would like to run the corda nodes separately without running runnodes jar.
How to run corda nodes individually?

Answer (score 0):

Following guide can be used to run node individually without running 'runnodes.jar'.
(Reference URL: https://docs.corda.net/running-a-node.html)

> Starting a Corda node from the command line
>
> Run a node by opening a terminal window in the node’s folder and running:
>
> `java -jar corda.jar`
>
> By default, the node will look for a configuration file called node.conf and a CorDapps folder called cordapps in the
>   current working directory. You can override the configuration file and
>   workspace paths on the command line

```
(e.g. ./corda.jar --config-file=test.conf --base-directory=/opt/corda/nodes/test).
```

> Optionally run the node’s webserver as well by opening a terminal
>   window in the node’s folder and running:

```
java -jar corda-webserver.jar
```